# Is my proof for disjoint perfect matching correct?

Tags: graph-theory

I want to show the following:
An $n$-regularly bipartite graph has $n$ pairwise disjoint perfect matchings.

**My Proof:**

Use Induction for $n$. The $n= 1$ case is trivial. Now consider $n\to n+1$. Take an edge away so this case was already proven and because of Hall's theorem we're done.

I'm not sure, is this proof okay?

Comment: You can't use the induction hypothesis on the graph from which you removed an edge, as it is not regular anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G(A,B)$ a d-regular bipartite graph. By the Hall's theorem, we need to show that for all $S \subset A$ ocurrs $|\Gamma(S)| \ge |S|$, where $\Gamma(S)$ is the neighborhood of $S$. But, because for all vertex in $|\Gamma(S)|$ the degree is $d$, we have $|S|\cdot d \le  |\Gamma(S)|\cdot d$